# HDMI Passthrough on TV

Tags: hdmi, video

I am researching the feasibility of using a Raspberry Pi as a pass-through device on my TV.

The goal is to put this in the middle of a connection between the cable box and the tv. I would like the cable box signal to still show on the TV but when the pi device is enabled, I would like that to display on the screen as well. Essentially working similarly as a smart TV does when you bring up the apps. The TV keeps playing whatever it has going but then the programming for the onscreen buttons and images appears over the cable box images.

This would be just the first part of what I want to achieve but I feel this is the most difficult part, and I am unsure where to start with it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like a really ambitious project, because even though the Pi has an HDMI out, it does *NOT* have an HDMI input.  That means you'd have to likely use the GPIO pins for that.  A good starting point would be some good HDMI interface resources (maybe http://www.hdmi.org/installers/insidehdmicable.aspx) and a GPIO pinout and tutorial guide (like http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/)